# How to upload multiple csvs without saving or using ORM

Tags: python, flask

I wish to have a single web page with two uploads (`input` type=submit), which accepts two csvs and adds their contents. e.g.:

```
# csv1
col1,col2
1,2
3,4

# csv2
col1,col2
10,20
30,40
```

Expected output:

```
col1,col2
11,22
33,44
```

But I don't care about the output for the moment; just the input functionality of implementing two `<input type="submit">` fields, and storing their contents somewhere. I'd like to do this without having to save this (i.e. using `file.save`), because this might cause errors with multiple users saving multiple files in the server directory (I think?). I can't really use the `models.py` ORM either, because different users may use different input column names (e.g. `c1`, `c2`, etc.), and the number of columns is variable. However, we can assume that the two inputs will always be of the same dimension.

I was able to write a route to handle *one* `<input>` element, but I'm not sure how to do *two*. What I have so far is:

**app.py** ([source])(https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/59622/not-able-to-parse-a-csv-file-uploaded-using-flask)

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template
import io
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file found"

    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    csv_contents = [] # this will be a list of lists
    for row in csv_input:
        print(row)
        csv_contents.append(row)

    # automatic download of output commented out
    #stream.seek(0)
    #result = transform(stream.read().replace("=", ","))

    #response = make_response(result)
    #response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return redirect("/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload CSV</h1>
    <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="data_file" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write two routes, one for each `input` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can just modify the `index.html` and use a single `submit` field (button) to submit the POST request.

In **app.py**, change `transform_view()` to:

```
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    f = request.files['input_file1']
    if not f:
        return "Input file 1 not found!"
    f = request.files['input_file2']
    if not f:
        return "Input file 2 not found!"

    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    csv_contents = [] # this will be a list of lists
    for row in csv_input:
        csv_contents.append(row)

    stream = io.StringIO(g.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    csv_contents2 = [] # this will be a list of lists
    for row in csv_input:
        csv_contents2.append(row)

    return redirect("/")
```

And **index.html** gets changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Input files (csv)</h1>
        <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="input_file1" id="input_file1">
            <input type="file" name="input_file2" id="input_file2">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```